# File Open Dialog Crash

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

I have run into weird crash in my application, caused by the file open dialog.

The application is written in C++ (Visual Studio 13 with latest patches) and calls the Win32 API directly and is running on Windows 10.

To crash the application, I just bring up the file open dialog (which opens to the d: drive), move to the top folder entry field and type in C (planning to change to the c: drive) and that causes this unhandled exception error.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5BAA7527 (ieframe.dll) in app.exe: 0xC00000FD: 
Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x05132000).
```

That unhandled exception then kills the application.

If I run the same application inside the debugger in release mode I get the same exception inside the debugger:

[image: Debugger Crash]

The debugger displays no call stack since the crash is actually deep inside Windows (i.e. inside ieframe.dll).

But if I hit Continue the application runs just fine and displays this as a tool tip in the file open dialog.

[image: File Open Dialog]

Also if, I now redo the file open a second time, now there is no exception.

Finally if I run the code in debug mode I get no exception at all.

So it looks like because the debugger caught the exception my application did not crash where as running outside the debugger the uncaught exception kills the application.

Also it looks like some option specific to the release build might be causing the crash as the debug version does not have the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Being *"deep inside Windows"* doesn't prevent display of a call stack. You even get symbolic information by using the [Microsoft public symbol server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552208.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

It turns out this was an issue with the release build settings. In particular it was related to the stack linker settings.

Comment: @ReazMurshed There is not one link in this answer. Please review more carefully.